# How to manage component states (loading, error, data) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented the following code to fetch data and render a component if everything goes well along with checking loading, error states.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Posts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState({ status: false, message: "" });

  const fetchPosts = () => {
    setLoader(true);
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        );
        // throw new Error("Some error occured");
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.error) {
           setError({ status: true, message: data.error });
        } else {
           setPosts(data);
        }
        setLoader(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        setError({ status: true, message: error.message });
        setLoader(false);
      }
    }, 2000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  if (loader) return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
  if (error.status) return <h3>Error: {error.message}</h3>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      {posts.length === 0 && <h3>There are no posts</h3>}
      {posts.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <Post post={post} key={post.id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

Is this the right way to handle loading, error and success states when fetching data? or is there a better and more elegant solution than repeating this for every component?

Comment: The code looks fine . you can make a small refactor by adding a finally block next to the catch block and move your `setLoader(false);` inside it . with this change you can remove the `setLoader(false);` from both your try and catch block . Also if i may ask why we have `setTimeout` ?

Comment: You could create a custom fetch hook and pass the needed params to it. See this nice example: 
https://typeofnan.dev/writing-your-own-usefetch-hook-in-react/

Comment: @Shyam setTimeout is just for testing to view the loading state as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for `data.error` in the `try` block, you could check for `response.ok`; if it is true, call `response.json()`, otherwise throw an error.

Also move the `setLoader` call to the `finally` block to avoid the duplicate calls in `try` and `catch` blocks.

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(...);

    if (response.ok) {
       let data = await response.json();
       setPosts(data);
    } else {
       throw new Error(/* error message */);
    }
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    setError({ status: true, message: error.message });
} finally {
    setLoader(false);  
}
```

If you want to check for `data.error` property in a response, you can change the following `if` condition

```
if (response.ok) {
```

to

```
if (response.ok && !data.error) {
```

> is there a better and more elegant solution than repeating this for
> every component?

Make a custom hook to make the `fetch` request and use that in every component that needs to fetch data from the backend.

```
const useFetch = (apiUrl, initialValue) => {

   const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue);
   const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
   const [error, setError] = useState({ status: false, message: "" });

   useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData = (url) => {
         setLoader(true);
      
         try {
            const response = await fetch(url);

            if (response.ok) {
               let responseData = await response.json();
               setData(responseData);
            } else {
               throw new Error(/* error message */);
            }
        
         } catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
            setError({ status: true, message: error.message });
         } finally {
            setLoader(false);  
         }
      }

      fetchData(apiUrl);
   }, [apiUrl]);

   return [data, error, loader];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be good enough to do, but, to me, I would prefer not to set timeout for getting data, and I will use `.then` and `.catch` for better readable and look cleaner to me

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Posts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState({ status: false, message: "" });

  const fetchPosts = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json())  
      .then(data => {
        setPosts(data);
        setLoader(false);
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log("error", error);
        setError({ status: true, message: error.message });
        setLoader(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoader(true);
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  if (loader) return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
  if (error.status) return <h3>Error: {error.message}</h3>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      {posts.length === 0 && <h3>There are no posts</h3>}
      {posts.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <Post post={post} key={post.id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```